# Cómo hacer esta inserción en MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero hacer una inserción en PHP con datos que tengo en un array. El código que tengo es éste:

```
foreach ($EANsNoCoinciden as $key => $value) {
   
    $sql="INSERT INTO articulos_nuevos (`ean`) VALUES (".$value.")";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
    var_dump($resultado);
    if($resultado){
            echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".$value." "."fue insertado correctamente. <br>";
        }else{
            echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".$value." "."tuvo errores en la inserción en su correspondiente tabla. Se aconseja que se revise. El error tuvo que ver con Error: ". $sql ."\n". mysqli_error($conWebService); 
        }
```

El caso es que el contenido de $EANs no coinciden es el siguiente:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
```

Al ejecutar el código me sale el siguiente error:

```
Array to string conversion. El error tuvo que ver con Error: INSERT INTO articulos_nuevos (`ean`) VALUES (Array) Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'.
```

Entiendo que me lo está mirando como un array, pero he probado varias cosas (entre ellas un implode) y no he sido capaz de momento de que me haga la inserción bien. Ahora mismo no me inserta nada. ¿En qué estoy fallando? Muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas intentando insertar un array en un valor que debe ser un string. Ya que el elemento esta en un array (de un solo elemento) debes cambiar las referencias de `$value` a `$value[0]` :

```
foreach ($EANsNoCoinciden as $key => $value) {
  $sql="INSERT INTO articulos_nuevos (`ean`) VALUES (".$value[0].")";
  $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
  var_dump($resultado);
  if($resultado){
        echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".$value[0]." "."fue insertado correctamente. <br>";
    }else{
        echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".$value[0]." "."tuvo errores en la inserción en su correspondiente tabla. Se aconseja que se revise. El error tuvo que ver con Error: ". $sql ."\n". mysqli_error($conWebService); 
  }
}
```

En general, PHP interpretara una variable de tipo array como el literal `Array` cuando se convierte a string.

```
$variable=[1,2,3];
echo "Valores: " . $variable; /* 'Valores: Array' */
```

Comment: Perfecto. Ha funcionado. Muchas gracias :)